# Chinese remainder theorem and quadratic congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, quadratic-residues

By Chinese remainder theorem there is a solution to $x \equiv a_{1} \pmod{ p_{1}}, \ ..., \ x \equiv a_{k} \pmod{ p_{k}}$ if $p_{1}, \ ..., \ p_{k}$ are pairwise coprime and $a_{1}, \ ..., \ a_{k}$ are integers.

I know that $ x^2 \equiv a \pmod p$ doesn't always have a solution, however, $x^2 + y^2 \equiv a \pmod p $ has a solution $ \forall a \in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore I want to prove that there is a solution to $x^2 + y^2 \equiv a \pmod {p_{i}}, \ ..., \ x^2+y^2 \equiv a \pmod{p_{k}}$ if $p_{1}, \ ..., \ p_{k}$ are pairwise coprime.

One way of proving the Chinese remainder theorem is to find a solution (namely $ x = a_{1}m_{2}p_{2} + a_{2}m_{1}p_{1}$ where $m_{2}p_{2}+m_{1}p_{1}=1$) for  the first two congruences and there use induction.

Would it be possible to use a similar proof here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ with 
  $$ x^2+y^2\equiv a_i\pmod{p_i},\quad 1\le i\le k, $$
you can first find $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb Z$ satisfying 
  $$ x_i^2+y_i^2\equiv a_i\pmod{p_i},\quad 1\le i\le k, $$
and then find $x,y$ with 
  $$ x\equiv x_i\pmod{p_i}\quad \text{and}\quad y\equiv y_i\pmod{p_i},\quad 1\le i\le k. $$

Comment: Thank you so much.